# Error when trying to install angular on Suse server

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins, suse

I am trying to install angular on a Suse server as root, and I am getting the following error for reasons I cannot understand:

```
# npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install angular/cli
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'angular/cli'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.7.10-1.4-xen
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! cwd /root
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.63
npm ERR! path angular/cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I understand that a ENOENT error would suggest improper permissions, but as root I believe this shouldn't be a factor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the version of your npm is very old! Can you update it and try the install again?

Comment: @Ronald Woods check my answer for upgrading your node version.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your error message your `npm` and `node` versions are too old to install cli. Install the latest stable release from [Node js website](https://nodejs.org/en/) and check again with `node -v` and `npm -v` to see the versions. You can try with the latest stable version 8.12.0 of node. After installing the stable version of node you need to run the command  `npm install -g @angular/cli` again.